# Trying to remember a book about a kid with powers

Tags: identification-request

A long time ago I remember reading a book about a kid who fights some enemy (aliens I believe) but not much else. The only key fact I remember is that one of these enemies picked up a coin and bent it in half with their eyelid to demonstrate their strength. The enemies had tiers to them as well. I have a vague memory of there being an elephant on the cover, but I cannot say for certain

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found it! It was *The Dangerous Days of Daniel X* by James Patterson. The specific excerpt can be found from [this pdf (hit download)](https://issuu.com/jamespatterson/docs/daniel_x_dangerous_days_excerpt) on page 21

Quote:

> “Oh, I hope not. Say, I’ve read you have Level 4 strength.
>   True or false?”
>   Orkng took out a quarter and bent it in half — with its
>   eyelid!

Comment: :) Don't forget to accept your own answer!

Comment: thanks for the reminder!